# If the vectors $a_1, ..., a_n$ are expressed linearly with the vectors $b_1, ..., b_k$, then $r(A)\le r(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can you give me an intuition for the following statement:

If the vectors $A=\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ are expressed linearly with the vectors $B=\{b_1, ..., b_k\}$, then $rank(A)\le rank(B)$.

I will use $rank(X)=r(X)$ as a notation.

So basically we have something like this: the set of vectors $A=\{a_1, ..., a_n\}$  and $B=\{b_1, ..., b_k\}$ and we know $(\forall a\in A)(a\in span(B))$.

We can then write $$\begin{cases}a_1=\lambda_{11}b_1+\lambda_{12}b_2+...+\lambda_{1k}b_k\\ \dots \\a_n=\lambda_{n1}b_1+\lambda_{n2}b_2+...+\lambda_{nk}b_k\end{cases}$$

$$A\cup B=\{a_1, ..., a_n, b_1, ..., b_k\}$$ The given solution goes as follows:

We have $r(A\cup B)=r(B)$ as $A$ and $B$ are linearly dependent and $r(A)\le r(A\cup B)=r(B)$ which gives $r(A)\le r(B)$.

I really don't understand where these inequalities all come from. Maybe the reason for that is I don't have a good intution on rank of **set of vectors which we define as the maximum number of linearly independent vectors in the set**. May you help me understand what exactly is going on?

Comment: One thought: all the lambdas could be 0, so r(A) would equal 0 in that case, which is less than r(B).  Do you see that?  More generally, the set A could only be a non-trivial combination of a subset of the vectors in B.  So r(A) <= r(B).

Comment: By definition, $r(A)$ is the number of linearly independent vectors in a set $A$. So the first equality $r(A\cup B)=r(B)$ is immediately clear. Including the vectors $a_i$'s to the set of vectors $B$ does not add any new linearly independent vector.

Comment: @Nothingspecial, okay, but it actually is the maximum number of independent vectors in a set. I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @MathStudent I don't know what you mean by the word "maximum" in this context. Every set of a vectors can be reduced to a maximal linearly independent subset... The size of this maximal L.I.  subset is the rank.

Comment: @MathStudent As an example this linearly dependent set of vectors $\{(1,0), (2,0), (1,1), (0,1)\}$ can be reduced to $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ or $\{(1,0), (1,1)\}$ (the maximal L.I. subset is not unique) so its rank is $2$ though it contains $4$ vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set of vectors $\mathscr P =\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$, its rank $r(\mathscr P)$ is the maximal number of linearly independent vectors in $\mathscr P$.

As an example, consider this linearly dependent set of vectors $\{(1,0),(2,0),(1,1),(0,1)\}$ over $\mathbb R^2$.

All vectors of this set can be sufficiently generated by $2$ L.I. vectors only. Pick $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, you can write all other vectors as their linear combination. Thus, the rank of this set is $2$ even though it contains $4$ vectors.

Now, consider your problem statement.

Given set of vectors $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\ldots, b_k\}$ such that
$\begin{cases}a_1=\lambda_{11}b_1+\lambda_{12}b_2+...+\lambda_{1k}b_k\\ \dots \\a_n=\lambda_{n1}b_1+\lambda_{n2}b_2+...+\lambda_{nk}b_k\end{cases}\tag*{}$

Think of $A\cup B$ in the sense $\{b_1,\ldots, b_k, \color{red}{a_1, a_2,\ldots,a_n}\}$.

The newly added vectors (in red) to the set $B$ are already linear combination of $b_i$'s. This means that you have not added any new linearly independent vector. Thus, the rank remains same i.e., $r(A\cup B)=r(B)$.

Coming to the inequality, $A\cup B$ is superset of $A$ which means that it already contains all vectors of $A$ and many more new ones.  Thus, $r(A\cup B)\geq r(A)$.

I will update this answer if you need further clarification.